# ExtJS: Adding prototype to Ext-wrapped DOM element

Tags: jquery, extjs

In jQuery, I can add an extension to a jQuery DOM element like so:

```
jQuery.fn.blowUp = function() { ... }
```

Used like:

```
$("#myDiv").blowUp();
```

In ExtJS, instead of `$()`, one uses `Ext.get()`. Given that, how can I write my `blowUp()` as an extension on the return of `Ext.get()` so that I can:

```
Ext.get('myDiv').blowUp();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ext.get returns Ext Element, so you can probably try this

```
Ext.Element.prototype.blowUp = function() {...}
```

Good luck!